# Display popup when user visits the pages on the site for the first time

Tags: javascript

I want to display pop-us on few pages when the user visits them for the first time. I don't want the values to be stored in the cookies or local storage as the count of the pages is may vary.

Comment: May I know why you dont want to use cookies, seassions, localsorage or sessionstorage?

Comment: I am working on a e-commerce site and want to display the popup for dynamic pages whose count is a big number. just want to avoid looping through for that amt of time. so wanted to if any on the fly options are available

Comment: Share some code, show us what you have tried so far so we can help you.

Comment: Are you asking to show something the first time the user visits the site, or are you asking to show something each time the user visits *each page* for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sessionStorage for that, on the initial page load create an object and set it into the session and get the value as required.

```
var popup = {
    pages: ['home','about','contact']
}

//set the pages list into the session
sessionStorage.setItem('showPopup', JSON.stringify(popup));

//retrive the value
var array = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('showPopup'));

//it could be window.location.pathname
if(array.pages.indexOf('about') === -1){
  //show your popup
}
```